# Is there a way to get string literals from GCC?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction

I have been looking around for a while on google but no fruitful results. I am actually looking for a way to export or some how get list of all string literals e.g.

```
int main(){
    const char *p = "Hello";
    const char x[] = "World";
}
```

For compiling this code is there a way to know "Hello" and "World"?  I do know that they are available in disassemblers (used some in Windows). But is there some proper tool to actually dump these strings or somehow export them?

Comment: Can you make your question more clear ?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that? What about strings from `__FILE__` or `__func__` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write a simple tokenizer that recognizes strings and comments and ignores everything else.

Comment: I won't prefer doing that it will only increase complexity as I include header files and other stuff.

Comment: use it on pre-processor output

Comment: I believe someone must have done it, why would I go for such clumpsy and reinventish method?

Comment: @MaX So what if you include header files (there is no "other stuff")? Just run the program over all your sources.

Comment: @MaX "I believe someone must have done it" -- perhaps, but the whole world isn't reading this. "why would I go for such clumpsy and reinventish method?" -- uh, to solve your problem? It's not a common request.

Comment: I down voted this useless answer because C tokenizers are anything but simple, with several phases of parsing and tokenization.

Comment: @CrazyChenz You downvoted it because you lack basic reading skills. "that recognizes strings and comments and ignores everything else" is a simple tokenizer. I said nothing about "C tokenizers".  If you think the answer is useless, then you didn't read the question. P.S. "with several phases of parsing and tokenization" -- I've written numerous C compiler lexers and was on the C standards committee, and I can confidently say you have no idea what you're talking about.The lexer is the lexer, which is just one phase. And C phases are standards talk; real parsers fold several phases together.

Comment: To make it as clear as possible to clueless people who reflexively downvote answers without reading them or doing basic thinking, there's no need for a full C lexer to solve the OP's problem. And as perreal noted, the *simple* lexer can be run on preprocessor output, so it can even grab strings resulting from preprocessor stringization or concatenation.

Comment: Finally, such a simple lexer to extract strings from C programs can be written in a few lines of Perl ... considerably fewer than the number in these comments.

Answer (score 3):

I don't get the question completely. You have a source file, and when you compile it, you need GCC to tell you how many string constants you've used. Am I correct at interpreting this?

If yes, you can tell gcc to compile with "gcc -S source_file" . This will give you the .s file, which contains the string constants you've defined, against ".string" . You can parse this file for ".string" occurances and get the count (either manually or with "grep" piped to "wc -l")

Answer (score 1):

Without debug information, you can only know that they will simply be plopped into a read-only data area (probably the `.rdata` section, IIRC).

The linux [`strings`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings) utility will look at a binary file and dump out any recognized strings within the given length and encoding constraints.

Comment: strings is not much useful as it prints lots of other junks. Give I have source code and I can compile in debug mode is there any better tool? I think it would make more sense to use .o files instead of final compile file.

Comment: I don't have access to an appropriate platform at the moment. But I'm thinking that if you compile with [`-g`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Debugging-Options.html), and then look at the executable with `readelf -a` you may get more insight into variables like these. At least you should be able to get the addresses which will point you (literally) to the strings.

Comment: I am on Mac used ```gobjdump`` was not helpful any more hints?

Comment: It's `.rodata`. `readelf -p .rodata` will do some of it, but it won't find `"World"`, at least not consistently - that's inlined in the text section (look at the assembly) even with `-O0`.

Comment: @Mat, thanks for clearing some of that up. You're right. I would think for longer strings this may work better.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need exactly all the string literal constants in a C code? (Using the `strings` utility on the binary might be enough).

You could customize the GCC compiler, e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), for that purpose, but that could take you days and I feel it is an overkill.

You might also emit assembly code from GCC and parse that assembly code for string constants.

And of course, you could tokenize and parse the preprocessed form.

Comment: The OP doesn't even want to spend the minimal time it would take to write a short program (trivial in Perl) to recognize and spit out C strings.